# From tick by tick data to candlestick

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, finance, pandas

I've tick by tick data for Forex pairs

Here is a sample of `EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-06.csv`

```
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.207,1.23618,1.2363
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.209,1.23618,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.210,1.23618,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.211,1.23623,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.240,1.23623,1.23627
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.423,1.23622,1.23627
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.457,1.2362,1.23626
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:01.537,1.2362,1.23625
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:03.010,1.2362,1.23624
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:03.012,1.2362,1.23625
```

Full tick data can be downloaded here
http://dl.free.fr/k4vVF7aOD

Columns are :

```
Symbol,Datetime,Bid,Ask
```

I would like to convert this tick by tick data to candlestick data
(also called OHLC Open High Low Close)
I will say that I want to get a M15 timeframe (15 minutes) as an example

I would like to use Python and Pandas library to achieve this task.

I've done a little part of the job... reading the tick by tick data file

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
from datetime import *

def conv_str_to_datetime(x):
    return(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

df = pd.read_csv('test_EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-07.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'], converters={'Date_Time': conv_str_to_datetime})

PipPosition = 4
df['Spread'] = (df['Ask'] - df['Bid']) * 10**PipPosition

print(df)

print("="*10)

print(df.ix[0])
```

but now I don't know how to start rest of the job...

I want to get data like

```
Symbol,Datetime_open_candle,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price
```

Price on candle will be based on Bid column.

The first part of the problem is in my mind to get the first Datetime_open_candle (compatible with the desired timeframe, lets say that the name of the variable is dt1) and the last Datetime_open_candle (let's say that the name of this variable is dt2).

After I will probably need to get data from dt1 to dt2 (and not data before dt1 and after dt2)

Knowing dt1 and dt2 and desired timeframe I can know the number of candles I will have...

I've "just to" know, for each candle, what is open/high/low/close price.

I'm looking for a quite fast algorithm, if possible a vectorized one (if it's possible) as tick data can be very big.

Comment: you're on the right path: numpy and scipy contain fast, vectorized statistics functions that should let you do what you want to do.

Comment: You can also use Pandas - http://pandas.pydata.org/ which provides an abstraction layer over numpy and allows for frequency conversion, e.g. from minutely to hourly data. It should also allow you to process tick data into OHLC easier (and still efficiently).

Comment: It's nice to tell me that I'm on the right path to go (you've noticed my tags) ... but I'm definitely stuck. I tryed df2 = df.resample('1Min') but I get TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex

Answer (score 19):

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
                             Symbol      Bid      Ask
Datetime
2012-06-01 00:00:00.207000  EUR/USD  1.23618  1.23630
2012-06-01 00:00:00.209000  EUR/USD  1.23618  1.23631
2012-06-01 00:00:00.210000  EUR/USD  1.23618  1.23631
2012-06-01 00:00:00.211000  EUR/USD  1.23623  1.23631
2012-06-01 00:00:00.240000  EUR/USD  1.23623  1.23627
2012-06-01 00:00:00.423000  EUR/USD  1.23622  1.23627
2012-06-01 00:00:00.457000  EUR/USD  1.23620  1.23626
2012-06-01 00:00:01.537000  EUR/USD  1.23620  1.23625
2012-06-01 00:00:03.010000  EUR/USD  1.23620  1.23624
2012-06-01 00:00:03.012000  EUR/USD  1.23620  1.23625

In [60]: grouped = df.groupby('Symbol')

In [61]: ask =  grouped['Ask'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')

In [62]: bid = grouped['Bid'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')

In [63]: pandas.concat([ask, bid], axis=1, keys=['Ask', 'Bid'])
Out[63]:
                                Ask                                 Bid
                               open     high      low    close     open     high      low   close
Symbol  Datetime
EUR/USD 2012-06-01 00:15:00  1.2363  1.23631  1.23624  1.23625  1.23618  1.23623  1.23618  1.2362
```

Comment: woah! that's very impressive ! but I still have TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex I tryed this df = pd.read_csv('test_EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-07.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'], index_col=1) but it doesn't work

Comment: Add parse_dates=True, otherwise your index will be plain strings and resample does not like that. df = pd.read_csv('test_EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-07.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'], index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

Comment: I did df2 = pd.concat([ask, bid], axis=1, keys=['Ask', 'Bid'])

#Date = df2.index.get_level_values(1)
Date = range(len(df2))
Open = df2['Bid']['open'].values
Close = df2['Bid']['close'].values
High = df2['Bid']['high'].values
Low = df2['Bid']['low'].values
Volume = np.zeros(len(df2))

DOCHLV = zip(Date, Open, Close, High, Low, Volume)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
df['Bid'].plot()
plt.title("Price graph")
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
plt.title("Candlestick chart")
candlestick(ax, DOCHLV, width=0.6, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=1.0)
plt.show()

Comment: And I get this error message : TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64'). It seems to be because of Date = df2.index.get_level_values(1) which returns array(['2012-07-01T23:10:00.000000000+0200',
       '2012-07-01T23:15:00.000000000+0200',
       '2012-07-01T23:20:00.000000000+0200',
       '2012-07-01T23:25:00.000000000+0200',
       '2012-07-01T23:30:00.000000000+0200',
       '2012-07-01T23:35:00.000000000+0200'], dtype='datetime64[ns]') instead of array of datetime... I don't know how to convert it

Comment: To convert Date from Datetime64 to datetime you can do: Date.astype(object)

Comment: I ever tryed this, unfortunately it doesn't work, it converts to array of big int numbers In [145]: df2.index.get_level_values(1).astype(object)
Out[145]: 
array([1341177000000000000, 1341177300000000000, 1341177600000000000,
       1341177900000000000, 1341178200000000000, 1341178500000000000], dtype=object) see full code here http://pastebin.com/ne7Fjdiq I would like to have date for X-axis (not number of candle)

Answer (score 7):

The syntax in the answer from Overmeire is meanwhile deprecated.

Instead of this:

```
ask =  grouped['Ask'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')
bid = grouped['Bid'].resample('15Min', how='ohlc')
```

Use this:

```
ask =  grouped['Ask'].resample('15Min').ohlc()
bid = grouped['Bid'].resample('15Min').ohlc()
```